# Derivative with quotient rule

Tags: derivatives

Trying to get $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{20e^x}{(e^x+4)^2}\right]$.

After quotient rule: $$f'(x)=20\dfrac{e^x(e^{2x}+8e^x+16)-e^x(2e^x+8e^x)}{(e^x+4)^4}\\\\\\= 20\dfrac{e^{3x}+8e^{2x}+16e^x-2e^{2x}-8e^x}{(e^x+4)^4}\\\\=20\dfrac{e^{3x}+6e^{2x}+8e^x}{(e^x+4)^4}\\\\=\dfrac{20e^x(e^x+4)(e^x+2)}{(e^x+4)^4}\\\\=\dfrac{20e^x(e^x+2)}{(e^x+4)^3}$$

But Wolframalpha says it should be: $-\dfrac{20e^x(e^x-4)}{(e^x+4)^3}$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: the error is in the first line just before the last $8e^x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f'(x)=20\frac{e^x(e^{2x}+8e^x+16)-e^x(2e^{\color{red}{2x}}+8e^x)}{(e^x+4)^2}
$$
You also do $e^x\cdot 8e^{x}=8e^x$, which is wrong.

On the other hand, if you consider
$$
g(x)=\frac{x}{(x+4)^2}
$$
you have
$$
g'(x)=\frac{(x+4)^2-x\cdot 2(x+4)}{(x+4)^2}=
\frac{x+4-2x}{(x+4)^3}=-\frac{x-4}{(x+4)^3}
$$
Since
$$
f(x)=20g(e^x)
$$
you have
$$
f'(x)=20g'(e^x)\cdot e^x=-\frac{20e^x(e^x-4)}{(e^x+4)^3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(e^x+4)^2=2e^x(e^x+4)
$$
we have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{20e^x(e^x+4)^2-20\cdot 2e^x(e^x+4)}{(e^x+4)^4}=\frac{20 e^x(e^x+4)(e^x+4-2e^x)}{(e^x+4)^4}=
$$
$$
=\frac{20e^x(-e^x+4)}{(e^x+4)^3}
$$